# PHP OpCache on Amazon EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, php, amazon-efs, opcache

Looking for some validation of my thought process here. I don't have the stats to hand to back up my claims, but have enough experience with web hosting with and without EFS to be comfortbale in making it.

A Joomla or WordPress PHP site being served entirely from EFS (e.g. the document root is in EFS) - making use of Apache and PHP-FPM will be slower than one that is served from EBS. This is because of the inherent latency of EFS for per-file operations.
My understanding was that with Opcache enabled, all PHP scripts are compiled into Opcodes and stored in memory.
if `validate_timestamps` is set to `=0` then once a file is read from the file storage and compiled into Opcodes it is not then subsequently read.

What I don't understand is that even with the above set, requests to a page will still be slower on EFS. Even if the code base is held in memory.

Is my understanding incorrect and what else could be causing this latency?

Comment: What latency? Are you actually having a problem? We prefer to solve real problems here, rather than theoretical ones.

Comment: I'll use TTFB as my metric. On a disk based system it's only in a matter of milliseconds, on EFS it can be seconds, despite Opcache being enabled. I'm just curious if my understanding of Opcache is correct and what else could cause the file system activity..

Comment: Is opcache actually enabled, then? Does it have enough memory? What configuration demonstrates the problem?